When does the eliminant (resultant) from three variables into two variables vanish?

Definition. Consider a ring $\mathcal{R}$ and polynomials $P,Q\in \mathcal{R}[x]$. We define the eliminant $\mathrm{Elm}(P,Q)$ of $P$ and $Q$ by the determinant of their Sylvester matrix.

If $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$, $Q(x)=\sum_{j=0}^m b_j x^j$, then the Sylvester matrix of $P$ and $Q$ is the $(n+m)\times (n+m)$ square matrix given by alocating the column-vectors $(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$ and $(b_0,\ldots,b_m)$ in $m$ and $n$ columns, respectively, translating the entries one line downwards at each column and filling remaining entries with zero. This is somewhat boring to write in general, but becomes clear with an example.
Taking $n=3$ and $m=2$, the eliminant $\mathrm{Elm}(P,Q)$ is given by
$$
\mathrm{Elm}(P,Q)=\det \begin{bmatrix}
a_3 &0 & b_2 &0 &0\\
a_2 &a_3 & b_1 & b_2 & 0 \\
a_1 &a_2 & b_0 & b_1 & b_2 \\
a_0 &a_1 & 0 & b_0 & b_1\\
0 & a_0 & 0 & 0 & b_0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If $P,Q\in \mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, we can eliminate some of the variables, say $x_i$, just by considering $P,Q$ as elements of $\mathcal{R}[x_i]$, with $\mathcal{R}=\mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots, x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\ldots ,x_n]$. We can call this the eliminant in $x_i$ of $P$ and $Q$ and denote it $\mathrm{Elm}_{x_i}(P,Q)$. Notice that $\mathrm{Elm}_{x_i}(P,Q) \in \mathcal{R}=\mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots, x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\ldots ,x_n]$, which justifies the name eliminant.

My question is: Suppose we have $P,Q\in \mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$ of the form $P = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i(x) z^i$, $Q = \sum_{j=0}^m b_j(y) z^j$, i.e. $P$ and $Q$ can actually be seen as elements of $\mathbb{R}[x,z]$ and $\mathbb{R}[y,z]$, respectively. When can I say that
\begin{align*}\mathrm{Elm}_z(P,Q)\equiv 0\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]?\end{align*}

I've seen that, for $P,Q\in \mathbb{R}[x]$, we have $\mathrm{Elm}(P,Q)=0$ if, and only if, $P$ and $Q$ have a nonconstant common factor. Is this still true for the multivariable version above? That is to say $\mathrm{Elm}_z(P,Q)\equiv 0\in \mathbb{R}[x,y] \iff P$ and $Q$ have a nonconstant (read this as "depending on $z$") common fator in $\mathbb{R}[x,y][z]$?
I don't know the proof for the particular case. Maybe it can be done for any ring $\mathcal{R}$?

The determinant of the Sylvester matrix of two polynomials is often called their resultant

@J.W.Tanner Yes. I used eliminant just because I wanted to emphasize I'm interested in eliminating one of the variables. Tagged resultant though

@Derso Did you test some simple examples?

The resultant of $x^2+y^2-z^2$and $(\frac{x}2)^2+(\frac{y}{\frac12})^2-z^2$  wrt $z$ is $(\frac34)^2(x-2y)^2(x+2y)^2$ The zero sets, geometrically.

@RiverLi If $P = (z^2+1)(xz^3 +z^2+z+1)$ and $Q=(z^2+1)(yz^2+z+1)$, then we get $\mathrm{Elm}_z(P,Q)=0$. I think we have in general $\mathrm{Elm}(PQ,R) = \mathrm{Elm}(P,R)\mathrm{Elm}(Q,R)$ and $\mathrm{Elm}(P,P)=0$, so it would be just a consequence of these properties. However, if $\mathrm{Elm}_z(P,Q)\equiv 0$ (the zero polynomial in say $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$), what can I say? Do they still have a common factor (in $\mathbb{R}[z]$? or whatever)?
